# How can I assign multiple values to a single key in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, class, object, collections

My spreadsheet continuously refreshes data contained in the table based on a project number. There are 5 additional columns that contain manually inputted information (i.e. does not automatically refresh) associated with each project number. These columns essentially contain user comments and must stay associated with the project number through each refresh. When a refresh occurs, new project numbers may also be added to the list.

I am looking for a solution to store these 5 manually inputted columns with the project number.

Previously, we used a dictionary when only one key-value pairing was required. However, now we have multiple values for each key.

```
Public Function saveComments(rowOfCom As Integer, _
                             rowOfSafety As Integer, _
                             rowOfCompliance As Integer, _
                             rowOfCommercial As Integer, _
                             rowOfOperational As Integer, _
                             rowOfSIssue As Integer, _
                             ws As Worksheet) As Variant
    'Sub is meant to save comments associated with masterplan id's
    'We do this by first making one dictionary with every plan year and another
    '    dictionary that will store the mpids & comments
    'Idea is to loop through each ws, store each mpid and comment then run macro
    '    to update mpids then paste in new comments

    Dim mpDict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim numOfWS As Integer, count As Integer, rowCount As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim value As Variant

    'Get the number of mpDictionaries needed. Counts the sheets if its a year
    '    or Not set just in case a sheet is added

    With ws
        rowCount = .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

        For i = 2 To rowCount
            If mpDict.Exists(.Cells(i, 1).value) = False Then
                For j = 13 To j = 18
                    'Access the mpDict and store the MPID and Comment
                    mpDict.Add .Cells(i, 1).value, .Cells(i, j).value
                Next j
            End If
        Next i

        ' Debug.Print (yearDict.Item(ws.Name).Item(.Cells(2, 1).value))

        count = count + 1
    End With

    Set saveComments = mpDict

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do in this case is to build a compound entry for each key. This can be in the form of a `Class` object, another `Dictionary`, a `Collection` or almost anything. For the simplest of situations though, I just create a CSV list.

For example, if my data is

```
+--------+----+
| red    | 42 |
| green  | 36 |
| blue   | 49 |
| white  | 44 |
| orange | 25 |
| black  | 45 |
| purple | 32 |
| mauve  | 41 |
| cherry | 14 |
| lemon  | 32 |
| lime   |  6 |
| red    | 11 |
| green  | 17 |
| blue   | 13 |
| white  |  9 |
| orange | 23 |
| black  | 21 |
| purple | 38 |
| mauve  | 19 |
| cherry | 22 |
| lemon  | 42 |
| lime   | 48 |
| red    | 35 |
| green  | 37 |
| blue   | 44 |
| white  |  6 |
| orange | 41 |
| black  |  5 |
| purple | 15 |
| mauve  | 20 |
+--------+----+
```

Then I'll build a using code similar to

```
Option Explicit

Sub BuildDictionaryExample()
    Dim myDict As Dictionary
    Set myDict = New Dictionary

    Dim myData As Range
    Set myData = Sheet1.Range("A1:B30")

    Dim keyValue As Variant
    Dim thisRow As Range
    For Each thisRow In myData.Rows
        keyValue = thisRow.Cells(1, 1)
        If Not myDict.Exists(keyValue) Then
            myDict.Add keyValue, thisRow.Cells(1, 2)
        Else
            Dim newValue As Variant
            newValue = myDict(keyValue) & "," & thisRow.Cells(1, 2)
            myDict(keyValue) = newValue
        End If
    Next thisRow
End Sub
```